# How to set a default starting location for Google Maps?

Tags: google-maps

How can I set a default starting address for Google Maps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't really set a default starting address.

However, under "My Places", you can define addresses for "Home" and "Work". Then when you are using maps to get directions, you can use "Home" or "Work" as the start/end point instead of typing in a full address or lat/long coordinates.

[More information from Google Maps Help](http://support.google.com/maps/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=1626958&topic=1705612&ctx=topic)

Comment: Is this information still valid? For the "new" Google Maps? (It's been a year.) I find it _immensely_ annoying that USA is the default because I live on another continent. (I have already defined home and work addresses.)

Comment: @Torben: Yes, it's still valid.

Comment: There is a way to set the default starting location, I just can't remember how and can't find it on the web yet.  I had my chrome set up to do this, with the perfect zoom level of the denver metro area everytime i opened google maps.  I lost it when I deleted that chrome user.